# Passing an argument into a URL

Tags: javascript

I have a function, which takes a number as an argument. I was wondering how I could use this number to pass into a url which will then be used in a GET request.

Below is some of my code, the {{}} brackets below didn't work, I also tried template literals which for some reason also didn't work '`https://www.mywebsite.com/api/v2/${urlID}/fonts.json`'

```
function getID (ID) {

  var urlID = this.ID;


  var request = require("request");

  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/v2/{{urlID}}/fonts.json',
 };
```

Comment: Try [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `\`https://www.mywebsite.com/api/v2/${urlID}/fonts.json\``

Comment: And falling back onto simple string concatenation did not even occur to you …?

Comment: Use the [Querystring module](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

Comment: If you want to vote to close this question as a duplicate, fine, but it isn't just string interpolation.  Anyone doing this needs to be reminded to escape their URL data correctly.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Querystring isn't appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For your template to work, [you'll need backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
`string ${someVariable} another string`
```

Since you're putting data in a URL, you should also take care to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) so that any data is escaped properly for the URL.

Putting it all together:

```
url: `https://example.com/api/v2/${encodeURIComponent(ID)}/fonts.json`
```